# Repeating UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggered only once on watch

Tags: apple-watch, unusernotificationcenter

1. Registered with

   let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
   center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
       // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
   }
2. Created content

   let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
   content.title = "My title"
   content.body = "My body"
   content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
   content.categoryIdentifier = "my-category"
3. Created trigger time. Note: repeats = true

   let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 65, repeats: true)
4. Scheduled notification request. Note: identifier is unique

   let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: NSUUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
   center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

Comment: Same problem here. Did you solve it?